# Couldn't match expected type ‘b1’ with actual type ‘b’ HASKELL

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple haskell class:

```
class Funz a where
    (+.) :: a -> a -> a
    eval :: (Num b, Num c) => a -> b -> c


instance (Num d) => Funz (Constant d) where
    Constant a +. Constant b = Constant $ a+b
    eval (Constant a) b = a
```

however, when i compile it says

```
app/basics.hs:18:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘c’ with actual type ‘d’
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          eval :: forall b c. (Num b, Num c) => Constant d -> b -> c
        at app/basics.hs:18:5-8
      ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at app/basics.hs:16:10-37
    • In the expression: a
      In an equation for ‘eval’: eval (Constant a) b = a
      In the instance declaration for ‘Funz (Constant d)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: d (bound at app/basics.hs:18:20)
        eval :: Constant d -> b -> c (bound at app/basics.hs:18:5)
   |
18 |     eval (Constant a) b = a
   |                           ^
```

even though both a and b should be of type "Num"

Whereas i'm trying to return a

Edit: changed the names because people stubbornly continued to say that i thought two variables were the same when that clearly wasn't the problem

Update: changed all the ambiguous Num into Double, since there doesn't seem to be a way to convert any Num into Double

Comment: The class looks wrong to me. What's the intent? Right now the class promises too much, i.e. the ability to apply a value of type `a` to any numeric type `b` (possibly completely unrelated to `a`). If we have `Constant Float`, how do we turn that into -say- `Integer->Integer`? That looks impossible to do in a meaningful way. To stress the point: addition is usually defined as `Num a => a->a->a`, and could not instead be defined as `(Num a, Num b) => a->b->b` since you can't meaningfully add numbers from any two numeric types.

Comment: Do you suggest changing to ``` a ->b->c ``` where b and c are of typeclass Num? Also there is no intent, i'm just trying to learn the language

Comment: Sorry, but that would be even worse :-/ That promises to be able to apply any a (caller's choice) to any b (caller's choice) and get any c (again caller's choice). We can't keep the promise later on, it's too strong. I guess `Funz a` should mean "`a` is a function-like type that can be added with itself". If so perhaps you need more advanced type machinery like type families. Before learning that advanced stuff, though, I'd recommend you become familiar with the basics like `data` types, constructors, and pattern matching (if you are not already familiar with that).

Comment: The `Num b`, is not the `b` in your `Constant b`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, you are thinking as OOP programmer.

Let's look at the following function:

```
foo :: a -> b
```

what it does basically? It has power to "convert" any value of any type to another value of another type (maybe the same). This seems absurd, it can't do that. You can't even implement it like this:

```
foo x = x
```

since this means that the result type must always be the same as the argument type, but the function type promises a different thing, the result type can be any and not the same as the argument type.

In Haskell, the context in which you "use" a function matters. In one context the argument type and value type will be one, in another they may be different. TypeChecker garants that a function can be "used" in some context if not you will get type error.

Basically, `foo :: a -> b` has extar two arguments which applied by the compiler itself. That two arguments are the type of `a` and type of `b`. So, "full" type of `foo` is `foo :: Λa.Λb. a -> b` (it is pseudocode) or sometimes write `foo :: forall a b . a -> b`. Compiler from the context provides this two types. Also, in *GHC* you have extension *TypeApplications* which allow you provide types manually.

You can say, Ok, but what if I provide type class constraints, like that:

```
foo :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b
```

can I implement like this `foo x = x`? The constraints say that the function argument and its result is a number, so why can't I just return it?

No, you cant, because the constraints will only limit the possible argument types and function values (they should be instances of the Num type class), but they can still be different.

There is no type inheritance in Haskell. A type class is a different thing than a class in OOP. In Haskell you can replace using type classes by the records. Let's declare alternative of type class `Num`.

```
data NumCls a = NumCls
  { numAdd :: a -> a -> a
  , numMul :: a -> a -> a
  , ...
  }

numClsInt :: NumCls Int
numClsInt = NumCls { ... }
```

Let's define `square` function in two manners:

```
square1 :: Num a => a -> a
square1 x = x * x

square2 :: NumCls a -> a -> a
square2 (NumCls{numMul}) x = x `numMul` x
```

In compiler is stage *desugar* where a type class declarations translates to records (like `NumCls`), a type class instance declarations translates to records definitions (like `numClsInt`), a function like `square1` translates to a function like `square2` and apply right records from the context of where a function used. So this is basically how type classes work in Haskell, no any magics.